# How to insert data on mongo DB

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

i'm learning how to code, and i'm currently on Flask, django, MongoDB framework.

I'm trying to create a new user and adding it to my mongodb. when i "send it" on postman i get this error: *DeprecationWarning: insert is deprecated. Use insert_one or insert_many instead.
id = mongo.db.users.insert(*

I've already tried using the suggestions on the error message above but still ain't working

Here's my code:

```
def create_user():
#recieving data
username = request.json['username']
password = request.json['password']
email = request.json['email']

if username and email and password:
    hashed_password = generate_password_hash(password)
    id = mongo.db.users.insert(
        {'username': username, 'email': email, 'password': hashed_password}
    )
    response = {
        'id': str(id),
        'username': username,
        'password': password,
        'email': email
    }
    return response
```

i'm sure it's just me being totally noob on the subject, but i couldn't find the solution. Thanks!

Comment: Since you are inserting one document into the collection, use `insert_one`: see the [usage of insert_one](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#inserting-a-document).

Comment: `DeprecationWarning` is not an an error, just a warning. Do you get an actual error with `mongo.db.users.insert_one` ?

Comment: Also you should not use id as a variable name as it's a Python built-in. I would go for `user_id`.

Comment: I already tried inser_one and insert_many.  For insert_one, postman keeps waiting for the db to respond, and if a put insert_many and sent the postman request i get this error: "TypeError: document must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, bson.raw_bson.RawBSONDocument, or a type that inherits from collections.MutableMapping"

Also, already changed id to user_id, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The method you are attempting to use (`insert`) has been deprecated for a few versions, as mentioned in the error message. You can use `mongo.db.users.insert_one` for one row, or `mongo.db.users.insert_many` for a lot of rows.